# dialog box using using radio button selection

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on following code snippet

```
<div id="check-boxes" >
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optradio">Sun</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optradio">Mercury</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optradio">Venus</label>

    </div>

    <div id="planets-details">
        <div id="sun">
            The Sun is a star - it is not a planet. Our Sun is just like the stars we see in the night sky.     
        </div>
        <div id="mercury">
            Mercury is a small, rocky planet.    
        </div>
        <div id="venus">
            Venus is a small, rocky planet blanketed in a thick layer of yellowish clouds. 
        </div>
```

Now I want that if I select a radio button like Sun then a diolog box gets appeared on the page showing sun details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the details are in the same order as the inputs, you could do it like this:

```
$('#check-boxes input:radio').click(function() {
  $('#planets-details > div').hide();      //hide all details

  $('#planets-details > div')
    .eq($(this).parent().index())          //show details for the clicked
    .show();                               //... input's label's index
});
```

Note that IDs are not needed for each planet using this method.

**Snippet:**

```js
$('#check-boxes input:radio').click(function() {
  $('#planets-details > div').hide();      //hide all details
  
  $('#planets-details > div')
    .eq($(this).parent().index())          //show details for the clicked
    .show();                               //... input's label's index
});
```

```css
#planets-details > div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="check-boxes">
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="optradio">Sun
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="optradio">Mercury
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="optradio">Venus
  </label>
</div>

<div id="planets-details">
  <div>
    The Sun is a star - it is not a planet. Our Sun is just like the stars we see in the night sky.
  </div>
  <div>
    Mercury is a small, rocky planet.
  </div>
  <div>
    Venus is a small, rocky planet blanketed in a thick layer of yellowish clouds.
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If the details aren't necessarily in the same order as the inputs, but their IDs are the same as the text that follows the inputs (in lowercase), you could do this:

```
$('#check-boxes input:radio').click(function() {
  $('#planets-details > div').hide();

  $('#' + $(this).parent().text().trim().toLowerCase()).show();
});
```

**Snippet:**

```js
$('#check-boxes input:radio').click(function() {
  $('#planets-details > div').hide();
  
  $('#' + $(this).parent().text().trim().toLowerCase()).show();
});
```

```css
#planets-details > div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="check-boxes">
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="optradio">Sun
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="optradio">Mercury
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="optradio">Venus
  </label>
</div>

<div id="planets-details">
  <div id="mercury">
    Mercury is a small, rocky planet.
  </div>
  <div id="sun">
    The Sun is a star - it is not a planet. Our Sun is just like the stars we see in the night sky.
  </div>
  <div id="venus">
    Venus is a small, rocky planet blanketed in a thick layer of yellowish clouds.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with Jquery.

Your code should look smothing like that :

```
$('#mydiv').click(function() {
   if($('#radio_button').is(':checked')) { 
      $('#divtobedisplayed').show() 
   }
});
```